# Div won't reposition and appear on .mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to make some infoboxes(.kontaktbox, .delovnicasbox) move and appear when I mouseover text in my footer(.kontakt, .delovnicas). I want them to appear next to mousepointer and then disappear again when mouse isn't hovering anymore (that's why I used .mouseover/.mouseout). My function doesn't work, no idea why. Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

```js
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  mouseX = e.pageX;
  mouseY = e.pageY;
});
$(".kontakt").mouseover(function() {
  $('.kontaktbox').css({
    'top': mouseY,
    'left': mouseX
  }).fadeIn('slow');
});
$(".kontakt").mouseout(function() {
  $('.kontaktbox').fadeOut('slow');
});
$(".delovnicas").mouseover(function() {
  $('.delovnicasbox').css({
    'top': mouseY,
    'left': mouseX
  }).fadeIn('slow');
});
$(".delovnicas").mouseout(function() {
  $('.delovnicasbox').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```css
body {
  /*ozadje strani*/
  background-image: url("images/background_test.jpg");
  background-size: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  /*krčenje strani*/
  min-width: 49.5em;
  font-family: verdana;
  color: #000000;
}
/*splošno linki*/

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*velikost celotne vsebine*/

.layout {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}
.bannerlayout {
  text-align: center;
}
#ijs_logo {
  display: inline-block;
}
#headersign {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 200%;
}
.topmenulayout {
  text-align: center;
}
#topmenu {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #330033;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.menutext {
  display: inline-block;
}
#linkijs {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#linkeng {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
}
/*container za linkboxe*/

#linkpanel {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.linkboxdivider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 38em;
  height: 18em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
.linkbox {
  /*linkbox positinoning*/
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  /*style*/
  background-color: #ffcc99;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 17em;
  height: 17em;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#novosti {
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
}
#knjižnica {
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 0px;
}
#čitalnica {
  border-radius: 30px 0px 30px 30px;
}
#servisi {
  border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
}
.linkboxtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.linkboxlink {
  color: #000000;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.footerlayout {
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #330033;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.kontakt {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.delovnicas {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
}
/*napis pod footerjem*/

.underfooter {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 90%;
}
#copyright {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#adminmail {
  vertical-align: top;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#adminmaillink {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.delovnicasbox {
  background-color: #ffcc99;
  padding: 1%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
  width: 12em;
}
.kontaktbox {
  background-color: #ffcc99;
  padding: 1%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
  width: 12em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Domača stran znanstveno informacijskega centra</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="defsi.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="magic.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="layout">
    <tr class="bannerlayout">
      <td>
        <img id="logo" src="images/ijs_logo.gif" alt="IJSlogo" />
        <p id="headersign">ZNANSTVENO INFORMACIJSKI CENTER</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="topmenulayout">
      <td>
        <div id="topmenu">
          <a href="http://www.ijs.si/">
            <p class="menutext" id="linkijs">IJS</p>
          </a>
          <a href="indexEN.html">
            <p class="menutext" id="linkeng">ENGLISH</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>
        <div id="linkpanel">
          <div class='linkboxdivider'>
            <div class="linkbox" id="novosti">
              <p class="linkboxtitle">NOVOSTI</p>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13795/Scripts/Allsi.asp">
                <p class="linkboxlink">e-knjige založbe Springer</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13782/Scripts/Titsi.asp">
                <p class="linkboxlink">nove elektronske revije</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13784/Defsi.asp">
                <p class="linkboxlink">novi izvodi tiskanih revij</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://www.sciencemag.org/archive">
                <p class="linkboxlink">Science Classic</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="linkbox" id="knjižnica">
              <p class="linkboxtitle">KNJIŽNICA</p>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13786/Defsi.asp">
                <p class="linkboxlink">predstavitev</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://www.cobiss.si/scripts/cobiss?ukaz=getid&amp;sblk=c&amp;lani=si&amp;bno=50108">
                <p class="linkboxlink">COBISS</p>
              </a>
              <a href="mailto:illijs@ijs.si">
                <p class="linkboxlink">medknjižnična izposoja</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://splet02.izum.si/cobiss/BibPersonal.jsp?init=t">
                <p class="linkboxlink">bibliografije raziskovalcev</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='linkboxdivider'>
            <div class="linkbox" id="čitalnica">
              <p class="linkboxtitle">ČITALNICA</p>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13782/Scripts/Titsi.asp">
                <p class=linkboxlink>elektronske revije</p>
              </a>
              <p class="linkboxlink">CD ROM-i</p>
            </div>
            <div class="linkbox" id="servisi">
              <p class="linkboxtitle">SERVISI</p>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13790/Defsi.asp">
                <p class=linkboxlink>splošno zanimivi</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13787/Defsi.asp">
                <p class=linkboxlink>samo za lokalne uporabnike</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="footerlayout">
      <td>
        <div class="footer">
          <p class="kontakt">kontakt</p>
          <p class="delovnicas">delovni čas</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="underfooter">
      <td>
        <p id="copyright">© ZIC IJS. Vse pravice pridržane.</p>
        <p id="adminmail">spletni mojster:<a id="adminmaillink" href="mailto:anton.verbovsek@ijs.si"> av</a>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="delovnicasbox">
    <p>pon.-čet.: 8:00-17:30
      <br>pet.: 8:00-17:00</p>
  </div>
  <div class="kontaktbox">
    <p>Institut Jožef Stefan
      <br>Knjižnica
      <br>Jamova 39
      <br>1000 LJUBLJANA
      <br>
      <br>tel: +386 1 47 73 304
      <br>fax: +386 1 47 73 152
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why not use a tooltip plugin?

Comment: mainly because this is the first time I heard about it. Found this solution while googling, thought I'd try it out and got stuck. I also like being able to style the tooltip.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Plugins let you style them, and integrate easily, especially since younare already using jQuery. qtip is one that I use, and I believe jQueryUI has its own tooltip implementation as well

Comment: checked it out, gotta say this looks like a much easier way to do this :) thanks for the input, gonna go install and implement now, deleting question in a bit

Comment: NP, glad you dont have to reinvent the wheel on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

You're usign the wrong selectors `id="kontakt"` but in jQuery you use `$(".kontakt")` with CLASS

Also instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout` use the better ones `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (or simply the `.hover()` method)

Your jQuery can also look like:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kecolo/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

```
var ttip;

$(document).mousemove(function(ev){
  ttip.css({left:ev.pageX, top:ev.pageY});
});

$("#kontakt").hover(function() {
  ttip = $('.kontaktbox').stop().fadeToggle();
});
$(".delovnicas").hover(function() {
  ttip = $('.delovnicasbox').stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

you just need to set a CSS `position` property to your tooltips in order to move them!

```
.delovnicasbox, .kontaktbox {
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: fixed, still doesn't work, will update question source

Comment: the -mouseover function doesn't seem to work, it also won't console.log a text or antything

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the selector in your javascript, it is working now, check the snippet in full page.
You have also to style better your #kontaktbox css, I have given an absolute position in order to have it on the page and You can change the values for it where to appear.

```js
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  mouseX = e.pageX;
  mouseY = e.pageY;
});
$("#kontakt").mouseover(function() {
  $('.kontaktbox').css({
    'top': mouseY,
    'left': mouseX
  }).fadeIn('slow');
});
$("#kontakt").mouseout(function() {
  $('.kontaktbox').fadeOut('slow');
});
$(".delovnicas").mouseover(function() {
  $('.delovnicasbox').css({
    'top': mouseY,
    'left': mouseX
  }).fadeIn('slow');
});
$(".delovnicas").mouseout(function() {
  $('.delovnicasbox').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```css
body {
  /*ozadje strani*/
  background-image: url("images/background_test.jpg");
  background-size: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  /*krčenje strani*/
  min-width: 49.5em;
  font-family: verdana;
  color: #000000;
}
/*splošno linki*/

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*velikost celotne vsebine*/

.layout {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}
.bannerlayout {
  text-align: center;
}
#ijs_logo {
  display: inline-block;
}
#headersign {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 200%;
}
.topmenulayout {
  text-align: center;
}
#topmenu {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #330033;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.menutext {
  display: inline-block;
}
#linkijs {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#linkeng {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
}
/*container za linkboxe*/

#linkpanel {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.linkboxdivider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 38em;
  height: 18em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
.linkbox {
  /*linkbox positinoning*/
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  /*style*/
  background-color: #ffcc99;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 17em;
  height: 17em;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#novosti {
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
}
#knjižnica {
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 0px;
}
#čitalnica {
  border-radius: 30px 0px 30px 30px;
}
#servisi {
  border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
}
.linkboxtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.linkboxlink {
  color: #000000;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.footerlayout {
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #330033;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#kontakt {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#delovnicas {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
}
/*napis pod footerjem*/

.underfooter {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 90%;
}
#copyright {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#adminmail {
  vertical-align: top;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#adminmaillink {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.delovnicasbox {
  background-color: #ffcc99;
  padding: 1%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
  width: 12em;
}
.kontaktbox {
  background-color: #ffcc99;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
  width: 12em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Domača stran znanstveno informacijskega centra</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="defsi.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="magic.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="layout">
    <tr class="bannerlayout">
      <td>
        <img id="logo" src="images/ijs_logo.gif" alt="IJSlogo" />
        <p id="headersign">ZNANSTVENO INFORMACIJSKI CENTER</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="topmenulayout">
      <td>
        <div id="topmenu">
          <a href="http://www.ijs.si/">
            <p class="menutext" id="linkijs">IJS</p>
          </a>
          <a href="indexEN.html">
            <p class="menutext" id="linkeng">ENGLISH</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>
        <div id="linkpanel">
          <div class='linkboxdivider'>
            <div class="linkbox" id="novosti">
              <p class="linkboxtitle">NOVOSTI</p>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13795/Scripts/Allsi.asp">
                <p class="linkboxlink">e-knjige založbe Springer</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13782/Scripts/Titsi.asp">
                <p class="linkboxlink">nove elektronske revije</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13784/Defsi.asp">
                <p class="linkboxlink">novi izvodi tiskanih revij</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://www.sciencemag.org/archive">
                <p class="linkboxlink">Science Classic</p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="linkbox" id="knjižnica">
              <p class="linkboxtitle">KNJIŽNICA</p>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13786/Defsi.asp">
                <p class="linkboxlink">predstavitev</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://www.cobiss.si/scripts/cobiss?ukaz=getid&amp;sblk=c&amp;lani=si&amp;bno=50108">
                <p class="linkboxlink">COBISS</p>
              </a>
              <a href="mailto:illijs@ijs.si">
                <p class="linkboxlink">medknjižnična izposoja</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://splet02.izum.si/cobiss/BibPersonal.jsp?init=t">
                <p class="linkboxlink">bibliografije raziskovalcev</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='linkboxdivider'>
            <div class="linkbox" id="čitalnica">
              <p class="linkboxtitle">ČITALNICA</p>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13782/Scripts/Titsi.asp">
                <p class=linkboxlink>elektronske revije</p>
              </a>
              <p class="linkboxlink">CD ROM-i</p>
            </div>
            <div class="linkbox" id="servisi">
              <p class="linkboxtitle">SERVISI</p>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13790/Defsi.asp">
                <p class=linkboxlink>splošno zanimivi</p>
              </a>
              <a href="http://greyhound.ijs.si:13787/Defsi.asp">
                <p class=linkboxlink>samo za lokalne uporabnike</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="footerlayout">
      <td>
        <div class="footer">
          <p id="kontakt">kontakt</p>
          <p id="delovnicas">delovni čas</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="underfooter">
      <td>
        <p id="copyright">© ZIC IJS. Vse pravice pridržane.</p>
        <p id="adminmail">spletni mojster:<a id="adminmaillink" href="mailto:anton.verbovsek@ijs.si"> av</a>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="delovnicasbox">
    <p>pon.-čet.: 8:00-17:30
      <br>pet.: 8:00-17:00</p>
  </div>
  <div class="kontaktbox">
    <p>Institut Jožef Stefan
      <br>Knjižnica
      <br>Jamova 39
      <br>1000 LJUBLJANA
      <br>
      <br>tel: +386 1 47 73 304
      <br>fax: +386 1 47 73 152
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```